# Player Prefab Won't Move on Key Input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am making a 2D top down game on unity, and my player will not move on key input with my script. My script is here:

```
Rigidbody2D body;

float horizontal;
float vertical;
float moveLimiter = 0.7f;

public float runSpeed = 20.0f;

void Start ()
{
   body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
   // Gives a value between -1 and 1
   horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"); // -1 is left
   vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"); // -1 is down
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
   if (horizontal != 0 && vertical != 0) // Check for diagonal movement
   {
      // limit movement speed diagonally, so you move at 70% speed
      horizontal *= moveLimiter;
      vertical *= moveLimiter;
   } 

   body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * runSpeed, vertical * runSpeed);
}
```

Any ideas on what I should do? I have tried three different scripts on this prefab and nothing happens.

Using this script, I have tried making a character prefab move on key input, but nothing happens:

```
Rigidbody2D body;

float horizontal;
float vertical;
float moveLimiter = 0.7f;

public float runSpeed = 20.0f;

void Start ()
{
   body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
   // Gives a value between -1 and 1
   horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"); // -1 is left
   vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"); // -1 is down
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
   if (horizontal != 0 && vertical != 0) // Check for diagonal movement
   {
      // limit movement speed diagonally, so you move at 70% speed
      horizontal *= moveLimiter;
      vertical *= moveLimiter;
   } 

   body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * runSpeed, vertical * runSpeed);
}
```

Comment: well you arent just decreasing your diagonal movement, you're decreasing all movement if not stationary.  you meant to normalise it. However,  when you debug it, what do you see?

Comment: Any other components active on your prefab? An animator or script by any chance? Also check if the rb doesn't have it's axis movement frozen.

Comment: I resolved it on my own, just followed Brackey's tutorial down to the letter. Thanks for the advice!